# Stack with char and double

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, evaluation, postfix-notation

So I'm currently working on a homework assignment that is using a Stack for Postfix and Infix expressions. My question is, how would I setup my stack so that I can push and pop chars and doubles. Right now I'm able to get the Infix to Postfix to work properly, but when I try to calculate the total for the postfix it bombs. Right now I'm using an array that will store the values of the letters, A-Z. This is my postFix eval function.

```
public double postFix(String infix, double[] numbers) throws Exception{
    Stack myStack=new Stack();
    for(int i=0; i<infix.length(); i++){
        char ch=infix.charAt(i);
        if(ch=='+'){
            char one=(char) myStack.pop();
            char two=(char) myStack.pop();

            double first=numbers[one-65], second=numbers[two-65];
            double temp=first+second;
            myStack.push((char) temp);
        }
        else if(ch=='-'){
            char one=(char) myStack.pop();
            char two=(char) myStack.pop();

            double first=numbers[one-65], second=numbers[two-65];
            double temp=first-second;
            myStack.push((char) temp);              
        }
        else if(ch=='*'){
            char one=(char) myStack.pop();
            char two=(char) myStack.pop();

            double first=numbers[one-65], second=numbers[two-65];
            double temp=first*second;
            myStack.push((char) temp);              
        }
        else if(ch=='/'){
            char one=(char) myStack.pop();
            char two=(char) myStack.pop();

            double first=numbers[one-65], second=numbers[two-65];
            double temp=first/second;
            myStack.push((char) temp);              
        }
        else if(ch=='^'){
            char one=(char) myStack.pop();
            char two=(char) myStack.pop();

            double first=numbers[one-65], second=numbers[two-65];
            double temp=Math.pow(first, second);
            myStack.push((char) temp);              
        }
        else{
            myStack.push(ch);
        }
    }
    return myStack.pop();
```

This is my Node class

```
private class Node{
    protected char data;
    protected Node next;

    private Node(){
        this.data=(Character) null;
        this.next=null;
    }

    private Node(char data, Node next){
        this.data=data;
        this.next=next;
    }
}
```

If there is anything else that you need from me please don't hesitate to ask

Should I create two stacks for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it...

I would make the stack nodes be able to hold either `char` or `double` data values. (Note that these will actually be the boxed types `Character` and `Double`.)

The node class would then have a `getValue()` method that returns the value, appropriately converted into a `double` type. This will ensure that the arithmetic operations work correctly.